# multiple different validation for the same entity

Tags: symfony

*Present fact :*

- I have a `User` entity;
- I have a `FormType` class for the `User` entity;
- I have a twig template to render the `FormType` class;
- I have a fully functional creation of a new user;

*Issue :*

- I would like to create a new template for editing exist users;
- I wouldn't like create a new form type just for editing;
- I would like to edit `User` with `FormType`, which is already used for creating new users;
- I always use a same entity `User` (create, edit, etc...);

For different render of this `FormType`, I would like to change the behaviour of validation system. For example:

- Creating: Password fields is mandatory
- Editing: Password is not mandatory (if blank then password doesn't change, but if not blank change in database)

When I read in web, all the solution based from unique constraints for one entity. Never apply different rule constraints for the same field entity. Indeed I don't understand how can use a same FormType for different action CRUD

**The question is : How can apply different constraints rules for the same fields entity dealing with differents logical utility.**

[image: Schema Entity Form constraints]

Answer (score 3):

Use [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation#validation-groups):

```
class User
{
    /** @NotBlank(groups={"registration"}) */
    private $password;

    // ...
}
```

```php
// registration
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $userModel, [
    'validation_groups' => ['registration', 'Default']
]);

// edit
$form = $this->createForm(UserType::Class, $userModel);
```

Comment: Ok validation groups is implementing for that. I read again this and I try to use this on my project monday. +1 now and check good response if it's run correctly on my context.

Comment: Validation groups can be handy but I find that using different form types tends to be easier.  Think about how you want the user to be able to change their password.